# subprocess call errors in python

Tags: python, subprocess, call

I have been having problems with subprocess call.

I wrote a very simple code (test.py) that simply prints "Hello….."

Then I did the following:

```
/sw/bin/python2.7
import subprocess
call (["test.py"])
```

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/sw/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
    File "/sw/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
    File "/sw/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can get it to work with os.system but I am keen to learn this subprocess method.
Where am I going wrong?

The test.py being called is in the same folder.

Comment: subprocess.call(["python", "test.py"]) ?

Comment: Thank you GHL. 

You are right, its :

    call(["python", "test.py"])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(["python", "test.py"])
```